# Django - Filter GTE LTE for alphanumeric IDs

Tags: python, django

I am trying to serve up our APIs to allow filtering capabilities using LTE and GTE on our ID look ups. However, the IDs we have are alphanumeric like `AB:12345`, `AB:98765` and so on. I am trying to do the following on the viewset using the Django-Filter:

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
item_id = AllLookupsFilter()

   class Meta:
      model = MyModel
      fields = {
        'item_id': ['lte', 'gte']
      }
```

But the issue is, if I query as: `http://123.1.1.1:7000/my-entities/?item_id__gte=AB:1999` or even `http://123.1.1.1:7000/my-entities/?item_id__lte=AB:100` it won't exactly return items with ID's greater than `1999` or less than `100` since the filter will take ID as a string and tries to filter by every character. Any idea how to achieve so I can filter on IDs so I get items exactly greater / less than the numeric ID (ignoring the initial characters) ?

Comment: What does "the filter will take ID as a string and tries to filter by every character" mean?

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is write a custom lookup. You can read more about them here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-lookups/

The code sample below has everything you need to define your own except the actual function. For that part of the example check the link.

```
from django.db.models import Lookup

@Field.register_lookup
class NotEqual(Lookup):
        lookup_name = 'ne'
```

In the lookup, you'll need to split the string and then search based on your own parameters. This will likely require you to do one of the following:

1. Write custom SQL that you can pass through Django into your query.
2. Request a large number of results containing the subset you're looking for and filter that through Python, returning only the important bits.

What you're trying to accomplish is usually called Natural Sorting, and tends to be very difficult to do on the SQL side of things. There's a good trick, explained well here: https://www.copterlabs.com/natural-sorting-in-mysql/ However, the highlights are simple in the SQL world:

- Sort by Length first
- Sort by column value second

Comment: Do you have any example how to implement either of the two options  ? I'm fairly new to the queryset part of Django

Comment: I don't but it shouldn't be hard to write one using that first link. All you need to do is make a DB query in the function, then sort the results

Comment: Will it work if we store the IDs in our DB as strings ? and not integers ? Cuz we do store it as "AB:12344" in the DB. Wondering if all that effort works on string IDs

Comment: You would have to do some manipulations in the python code to split and turn it into numbers. Do you have another database field you might be able to use to sort things?

Comment: no. But that would be straight solution as to add a numeric field and just do usual sorting by that field